# PHP: find php files in folder and dimensionalize

Tags: php, class

I am new to PHP, coming from the .Net world. My project is a Report Server. each report is treated like a php file that goes to the database, gets json data, and prints it on screen for the user to see.

I am trying to get a list of php files in a folder, dimensionalize them, and get certain properties declared inside that file.

For example, i would have a file called: "sales_report.php"
Within that i would have:

```
class sales_report.php { 
Public $tags = array('sales','invoice','margin')
// code to fetch data from database, get json, and print report into html.
}
```

I need to be able to see the $tags, but i won't know this file/class exists until i have a previous code that dimensionalizes this class.

question: does anybody know how to dimensionalize a php file

Comment: "dimensionalizes"?? This question is very unclear. For starters, beyond "any ideas?" you haven't actually asked one!

Comment: yes i have. question: does anybody know how to dimensionalize a php file.

Comment: Well that depends. What the heck does "dimensionalize a php file" mean?

Comment: Sorry, "dimensionalize" is not a term that's really used in PHP development. You should clarify what that means.

Comment: ok maybe its more a visualbasic.net term. Dimensionalize is when you declare an object. since i was looking at files, i am assuming that php would return a string. i need to convert that string into an object..class.

Comment: Sounds like you basically want to `eval()` PHP code.

Comment: Don't eval(). Just include the file. Then, "Instantiate" is the term you want.

Comment: That is not how it works or what it's called in VB.NET, either!

Answer (score 1):

Look at `glob()` to do what you're asking: https://www.php.net/glob

Look at `_autoload()` for another way to do what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

'Dimensionalize' is not a word in PHP. If you require or include the file, the code within it is run. You may mean you want to 'instantiate' an object based on a class in your file.

```
require_once('sales_report.php');
$object = new sales_report();
echo $object->tags[0]; // prints 'sales'
```

Comment: thanks! the _autoload() looks promising. i will check it out and confirm the answer.